# setting up custom HTTP Health Checks on GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, health-monitoring

Apparently I cannot figure out how to do custom HTTP endpoint for Health Checks. Maybe I missed something or GCP doesn't offer it yet.

The [ElasticSearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-health.html) health check page describes various ways to check the EL cluster.

I was looking at the GCP health checks interface and it doesn't let us to add a URL endpoint, neither let us to define a parser for the health check to match against the "green" cluster.

What I was able to do is to wire in port 9200 and use a config like: 
port: 9200, timeout: 5s, check interval: 60s, unhealthy threshold: 2 attempts

But this is way not the way to go for EL cluster, as the cluster may respond but having a yellow/red state.

There would be an easier way without parsing the output just adding a timeout check like:

> GET /_cluster/health?wait_for_status=yellow&timeout=50s

Note: Will wait for 50 seconds for the cluster to reach the yellow level (if it reaches the green or yellow status before 50 seconds elapse, it will return at that point).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GCP health checks are simple and use the HTTP status code to determine if the check passes (200) - https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/health-checks

what you can do is implement a simple HTTP service that will query ES's health check endpoint parse the output and decide if status code 200 should be returned or something else.